# read excelsheet attachement from mail in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, attachment

i want to read excelsheet attachement from email and delete that mail after opening daily.can i get the c# code.

email type  IMAPS
TLS enabled  yes
port  993

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please do not ask us to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reading mail and extract and save the attachment you can use OpenPop:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/

For reading the excel sheet without have excel installed you can use NPOI:

http://npoi.codeplex.com/